# Problems with log in check

Tags: php

I write the following loginCheck code and the database schema I use is as follows:
userinfo:
username varchar
password varchar

code:

```
   <?php
    //set the MIME type to application/json
    //header("Content-Type: application/json");

    //get the username and password
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //require database operation
    require 'database.php';

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT username, password, COUNT(*) FROM userinfo WHERE username=?");

    if(!$stmt){
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => false,
            "message" => "an error occured, please try again"
        ));
        exit;       
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($returnedUsername, $hashedPassword, $count);

    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($count==1 && crypt($password, $hashedPassword) == $hashedPassword) {
        //all information provided is correct, start a session
        ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1);
        session_start();

        $previous_ua = @$_SESSION['useragent'];
        $current_ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        if(isset($_SESSION['useragent']) && $previous_ua !== $current_ua){
           die("Session hijack detected");
        } else{
           $_SESSION['useragent'] = $current_ua;
        }

        //create a token
        $_SESSION['token'] = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 10);
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => true,
            "token" => htmlentities($_SESSION['token']),
            "username" => htmlentities($_SESSION['username'])
        ));
        exit;
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => false,
            "message" => "Incorrect Username or Password"
        ));
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->close();
?>
```

The url is:
http://ec2-54-148-227-9.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/~beibeixhb/Calendar/calendar.php

I am not sure why it prevent me from logging in, any suggestions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.bestpractice

Answer (score 0):

You are using the hashed version of your password as a salt to the password entered and you expect that to be the same as the hashed password. I don't think this can ever happen.

```
crypt($password, $hashedPassword) == $hashedPassword
```

It's not clear from your code where you get the salt from, but if you didn't use salt to hash the password to start with, taking out that second argument of `crypt` should do the job for you.

Alternatively, use the right salt as a second argument to `crypt`.